# Redshift - Enable location services on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: location, redshift, geolocation

I have a problem with [Redshift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKL8x.png). It doesn't get the location from my geolocation provider 'geoclue'. The problem was more noticeable when I tried to use [Maps app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T8qJ.png) which said I should enable location services in order to be located. I just can't find any settings regarding this. Anyone? Thanks

P.S. Clicking on button "Location Settings" does nothing

Comment: What desktop environment is this?

Comment: I use Ubuntu with Unity shell (GNOME in background)

Answer (score 4):

From the terminal try:

`redshift -l list`

You should see: geoclue2

Try changing location provider to geoclue2

If you have redshift config file under `~/.config/redshift.conf` this can be changed there.

Answer (score 4):

I use Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 but should work the same:
**Settings > Privacy > Location services > on**
works for me, although the location accuracy is not perfect!